# Download PNG file to local machine using Dropbox.NET on UWP platform

Tags: c#, dropbox-api, windows-10-universal

I am able to upload PNG image to Dropbox folder however, I don't know how to download the PNG (or other images) from Dropbox. What I get from the tutorial page is:

```
async Task Download(DropboxClient dbx, string folder, string file)
{
    using (var response = await dbx.Files.DownloadAsync(folder + "/" + file))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(await response.GetContentAsStringAsync());
    }
}
```

Do anyone have the sample code for downloading file to local drive? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Dropbox API .NET SDK `DownloadAsync` method](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesRoutes_DownloadAsync_1.htm) gives you a [`IDownloadResponse`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/T_Dropbox_Api_Babel_IDownloadResponse_1.htm) which offers three methods for getting the file content:

- `GetContentAsByteArrayAsync`
- `GetContentAsStreamAsync`
- `GetContentAsStringAsync`

For example, to save the file content to a local file, you can do something like:

```
public async Task Download(string remoteFilePath, string localFilePath)
{
    using (var response = await client.Files.DownloadAsync(remoteFilePath))
    {
        using (var fileStream = File.Create(localFilePath))
        {
            response.GetContentAsStreamAsync().Result.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }

    }
}
```

That would download the file content from a file at remote Dropbox file path `remoteFilePath` to the local path `localFilePath`.

Comment: Thanks Greg for your help :) The solution you posted has give me idea on how to implement it in my project.

Comment: this worked for me... don't forget the `using System.IO;`

Answer (score 2):

After some findings and tryings, finally I found the solution:

```
public static async Task Download(string folder, string file)
{
    StorageFolder storeFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    CreationCollisionOption options = CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting;
    StorageFile outputFile = await storeFolder.CreateFileAsync("temp.png", options);

    using (var dbx = new DropboxClient(yourAccessToken))
    {
          var response = await dbx.Files.DownloadAsync(downloadFolder);
          {
               using (var file = await outputFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
               {
                    Stream imageStream = await response.GetContentAsStreamAsync();
                    CopyStream(imageStream, file);
               }
          }
     }
}
```

With a helper function:

```
public static void CopyStream(Stream input, Stream output)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        output.Write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
}
```

To upload file:

```
public static async Task Upload(string filename, string filePath)
{
    try
    {
        string TargetPath = "/data/" + filename + ".png";
        const int ChunkSize = 4096 * 1024;
        using (var dbx = new DropboxClient(yourAccessToken))
        {
            using (var fileStream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                if (fileStream.Length <= ChunkSize)
                {
                    await dbx.Files.UploadAsync(TargetPath, null, false, null, false, body: fileStream);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("File is too big");
                    await dialog.ShowAsync();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("Error uploading file. " + ex.Message);
        await dialog.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly would you please upload a sample code for upload file on Dropbox

Answer (score 0):

What @Greg said is correct. I would like to make a small change that localFilePath mentioned in the code, should have an extension also. For example it should be something like C:\Code\image.jgp and not something like C:\Code. If the filelocation specified does not exist, it will be created automatically and this code will work perfectly.

```
public async Task Download(string remoteFilePath, string localFilePath)
{
    using (var response = await client.Files.DownloadAsync(remoteFilePath))
    {
      using (var fileStream = File.Create(localFilePath))
      {
         response.GetContentAsStreamAsync().Result.CopyTo(fileStream);
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my logic to download a file using Dropbox.Net API:

```
private async Task Download(DropboxClient dbx, string remoteFilePath, string localFilePath) {
  using(var response = await dbx.Files.DownloadAsync(remoteFilePath)) {
    var fileSize = response.Response.Size;
    var bufferSize = 1024 * 1024;
    var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    using(var stream = await response.GetContentAsStreamAsync()) {
      using(System.IO.FileStream file = new System.IO.FileStream(localFilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)) {
        var length = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        while (length > 0) {
          file.Write(buffer, 0, length);
          var percentage = 100 * file.Length / (double) fileSize;
          Console.WriteLine(percentage);
          length = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And you can call it like:

```
Await(Download(dbx, url, @"yourDestinationFolder\" + item.Name));
```

Where **item.Name** is the full name of the downloaded file e.g. **setup.exe**